# using super pom only for testing

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I have a lot of maven projects, which are dependent on each other.

I already have a super pom for the actual projects and this works pretty well.

Now I want to create a super pom for all my integrationtests projects. I did it the same, but every time I run maven test it failed.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ***: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project** :**:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:** :**:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,**
>   :**:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,** :**:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,** :**:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ***:***:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

The problem is that maven looks for jar files but my project consists of war projects. Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>***-parent_IntegrationTests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>***_IntegrationTests</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>../***</module>
    <module>../***</module>
    <module>../***</module>
    <module>../***</module>
    <module>../***</module>
    <module>../***</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there a way to tell maven to use the war files instead of jars?

Edit: Sorry if it is not clear enough. I want a single maven project to run all my integrationtest projects. each one is a maven project. Therefor I want to use a pom with modules (all the integrationtest project) in it. But every integrationtest project contains dependencies to my other projects and the problem I want to fix is that maven does not find my compiled projects because it looks for jar files but my projects are war files.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference WARs as dependencies by using `<type>war</type>` in the dependency.

Comment: Is there also a way to do this for all modules? Because the super pom has only junit as dependency and the modules have their own ones.

Comment: Can you edit your question and give an example of what you want?